# Cannot use @EJB to instantiate my object in the WAR application

Tags: java, jsp, ejb, java-ee-6

I am learning Java EE and JSP. I have created an Enterprise Application project in NetBeans. 
I have the `EJB project` where all beans are and a `WAR project` where all web/client stuff is. 
My problem is that the annotation `@EJB` does not instantiate my Bean in the WAR application. Can I use `@EJB` outside the EJB application?

In the EJB project, I have these files:
CustomerRemote.java

```
@Remote
public interface CustomerRemote {
    public Customer createCustomer();
    public Customer getCustomer(int customerId);
    public void removeCustomer();
}
```

CustomerBean.java

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerBean implements CustomerRemote {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="testPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Customer createCustomer() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public void removeCustomer() {        
    }

    @Override
    public Customer getCustomer(int customerId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

In the WAR project, I have a file that my JSP page uses to communicate with the EJB stuff. The problem is that the CustomerRemote object is never instantiated. @EJB annotation does not seem to work because `customerRemote` always is null. But when instantiating it with the `lookup` method, it works! So why does not `@EJB` work?

```
public class CustomerProxyBean {

@EJB
private CustomerRemote customerRemote;

public CustomerProxyBean() {        
//    try {
//        InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
//        customerRemote = (CustomerRemote)context.lookup("java:app/SimpleShop-ejb/CustomerBean");
//        
//    } catch (NamingException ex) {
//        Logger.getLogger(CustomerProxyBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@EJB` annotation will work only in cases where your class is container-managed, that is EJB, servlet, JSP... In your case you put it into plain old Java object (POJO) so injection will not work, as you have experienced. Write your CustomerProxyBean as a stateless session bean, and you'll see the change.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid JNDI for some reason, you can use CDI and `@Inject` annotation to inject EJB and achieve wished behaviour, even in POJO:

```
@Inject
private CustomerRemote customerRemote;
```

Comment: So `CustomerProxyBean` is not container managed? I tried to put `@Stateless` annotaion above the class declaration, but it didn´t help.

Comment: `CustomerProxyBean` is not container managed, as it doesn't implement any interface and it is not properly annotated. Which Java EE version are you using? In Java EE 6, you can go without implementing any interfaces, but then you'll have to add also `@LocalBean` annotation in addition to `@Stateless`. Otherwise, implement Local or Remote interface, as you did in your `CustomerBean` bean.

Comment: Edit: you can go even without `@LocalBean` annotation (you'll have in both cases no-interface view), but the key is Java EE and EJB version that you are using. In case of Java EE 6/EJB 3.1 `@Stateless` should be enough to make your class stateless session bean, otherwise you'll also have to implement Local or Remote interface.